# try another random seed

Tags: r, random, error-handling

I need a code trying random seeds until a desired result is obtained or maximum number of attempts is reached. Here is an artifical example: function `smallr()` returns either random number < 0.2 or an error message. If the error is captured by `tryCatch` another attempt is made with different random seed and the procedured is repeated until maximum number of attempts (here 50) is reached.

```
smallr <- function() {
    r <- runif(1)
    if (r >= 0.2)
        stop("r >= 0.2")
    r
}

i <- 1
set.seed(1)
r <- tryCatch(smallr(), error=function(e) NA)
while(is.na(r) & i <= 50) {
    rm(.Random.seed)
    r <- tryCatch(smallr(), error=function(e) NA)
    i <- i + 1
}
r
```

Is it possible to do same within the exception handling system? (Perhaps using `tryCatch` function itself in a specific way?)

My actual motivation is to fit a series of complex regression models and overcome occasional lack of convergence by changing random seeds. Given this procedure is a part of even larger script I would prefer to keep the code as concise as possible.

Comment: I don't like the approach. While the wise thing to do is to check why convergence is so unstable, you can always restart your algorithm without reseeding at all (internal-state already changed). Of course you could save/export the seed for reproducability but the this would be not that scientific (look: it convergence with this random-path...). And regarding the tryCatch: I'm not an R-user and don't know much about error-handling; but if your algorithm returns state-messages, this could always be changed to some if-else-stuff.

Comment: Filtering on seeds to get a desired result is referred to as "cherry picking" and is a big no-no in simulation/computational statistics.

Comment: OK, folks, I will consider your no-no comments. But be sure - I was not trying to obtain any specific desired result, just to make the algorithm producing _any result_ even under conditions unfavorable for the algorithm's performance. After all I saw many times function arguments like "number of initialization attempts" and I intended to get something similar.

Comment: (First: sry for the large amount of spelling-errors in my first comment; i will leave it up for the content). What you refer to is a kind of multi-initialization, which is, as you said, often used. One prominent example is k-means for clustering. The thing is, that this approach is usually used when some step/optimization is heavily dependent on the initial-start-vector, like in most nonlinear (or let's be more specific: nonconvex) optimization tasks. In my opinion these single runs all share local-optimum convergence guarantees, therefore the restart.It looks a bit different to your task